# Input Checkbox cant get clicked

Tags: html, css, input, checkbox, label

I am tryinng to make a login but I cant check the checkbox.

I do not have a clue where the problem is.  Everything looks right and works, the checkbox is the only thing that does not. I also have not found anything in the web, so it would be really nice if anyone could help me here!

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.container {
    background-color: olive;
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.registerdiv {
    background-color: rgb(110, 110, 1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: thin;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

::placeholder {
    color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    width: 255px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: thin;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.checkbox {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input:focus {
    border: 3px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.input:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="header">Sign in</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="What's your username?" required />
            <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="What's your password?" required />
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /><label for="checkbox">Remember me</label>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Go ahead</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="registerdiv"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an important issue in your code is the `<label>` tag **overlapping** the `<input type="checkbox">`. Therefore, you do not have an interactivity with an `<input type="checkbox">`.

But it's better to go the right way:

You have specified the `for="checkbox"` attribute for the `<label>`, but forgot to specify the `id="checkbox"` attribute for the `<input type="checkbox">`.

Since the **for** attribute only refers to the **id** attribute of *another* element!

Do it in this way:

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.container {
    background-color: olive;
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}

.registerdiv {
    background-color: rgb(110, 110, 1);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.header {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.input {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: thin;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

::placeholder {
    color: rgb(46, 46, 46);
    text-align: center;
}

.btn {
    width: 255px;
    height: 33px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    outline: thin;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

label {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -17px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.checkbox {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.input:focus {
    border: 3px solid rgb(46, 46, 46);
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.input:focus::placeholder {
    color: transparent;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="header">Sign in</h2>
        <form>
            <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="What's your username?" required />
            <input type="password" class="input" placeholder="What's your password?" required />
            <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
            <label for="checkbox">Remember me</label>
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Go ahead</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="registerdiv"></div>
</body>
```